# My menu_main.xml do not show on my main_activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I just a newbie in android programming, i am building a new app from a tutorial.
I have make the main menu like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="id.go.kemenkeu.itjen_kemenkeu.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigate"
    android:title="@string/next"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"/> </menu>
```

and the MainActivity.Java like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_settings){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hi, Anda Baru Saja Menekan"+item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.navigate){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```

I call the +id/navigate in MainActivity.Java, but when i run in emulator, the style inside +id/navigate didn't show. What is wrong here?

Comment: add `onCreateOptionsMenu` to your Activity

Comment: thank you Phan Van, your suggestion is nice. I have try it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

you have to override createoptionmenu for intialize your own menu in toolbar.
try adding this in you activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without `onCreateOptionsMenu` you cant show `menu`. so add `onCreateOptionsMenu` to your `Activity` Class like,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must inflate the option menu
Add this line.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu` in you `Activity` and inflate the menu and check it
more details you have to check in [Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)